# Exibir resultados de uma busca de um array em outro

Tags: php

creio que minha dúvida seja simples, tenho 2 arrays, um que armazena os MACs do equipamento que esta sendo consultado **($cmdarr)** e outro que armazena os MACs do concentrador **($ips)**, eu desejo encontrar as ocorrencias do primeiro array $cmdarr no segundo $ips e exibir somente o campo [name] das ocorrencias encontradas.

```
print_r($cmdarr);
print_r($ips);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 00:1A:3F:6D:3D:C5
            [1] => 00:1A:3F:6D:69:49
            [2] => 
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [.id] => *80003470
            [name] => 47460
            [service] => pppoe
            [caller-id] => 00:1A:3F:64:3C:B5
            [address] => 179.189.141.238
            [uptime] => 14h57m8s
            [encoding] => 
            [session-id] => 0x81903470
            [limit-bytes-in] => 0
            [limit-bytes-out] => 0
            [radius] => true
        )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um foreach resolve o seu problema:

```
foreach ($ips as $ip) {
    if (in_array($ip['caller-id'], $cmdarr[0])) {
        echo "{$ip['name']}\r\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Uma adição que eu faria é trocar a comparação fixa na posição `$cmdarr[0]` por um outro `foreach` e dentro fazendo a comparação.

Comment: Obrigado amigo, era exatamente isso que estava querendo, resolvida a questão!